# X11 js-ctypes, XQueryTree acces wChild[i]

Tags: firefox-addon, jsctypes

```
        var wRoot = new ctypes.unsigned_long();
        var wParent = new ctypes.unsigned_long();
        var wChild = new ctypes.unsigned_long.ptr();
        var nChildren = new ctypes.unsigned_int();

        var rez = XQueryTree(_disp, w, wRoot.address(), wParent.address(), wChild.address(), nChildren.address())
        if(rez != 0) { //can probably test this against `None` instead of `0`
            var nChildrenCasted = ctypes.cast(nChildren, ctypes.unsigned_int).value;
            for(var i=0; i<nChildrenCasted; i++) {
                searchForPidStartingAtWindow(wChild[i]);
            }
        } else {
            console.warn('this window has no children, rez:', rez);
        }
```

I sucessfully get the `nChildrenCasted` it's 94.

However I can't access `wChild` elements, it should be an array

So problem is on the line: `searchForPidStartingAtWindow(wChild[i]);`

how to pass `wChild[i]`?

I tried:

```
var wChildCasted = ctypes.cast(wChild, ctypes.unsigned_long).contents;
console.log('wChildCasted:', wChildCasted);
```

I'm pretty sure its along those lines but i cant figure it out

full code, can be copy pasted and run from scratchpad:

https://gist.github.com/Noitidart/224f8999eb26ec52894f

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to cast from the raw pointer type to an ArrayType pointer:

```
var wChildCasted = ctypes.cast(wChild, ctypes.ArrayType(ctypes.unsigned_long, nChildrenCasted).ptr).contents;
```